# SQLite3/SQLCipher crash only with iOS 13+

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, ios13, sqlcipher

I have a test to get the column name and other metadata info from SQLite3 db. When I call `sqlite3_column_database_name(pStmt, 0);` my app crashes. This only happens when using it in conjunction with SQLCipher. The crash log isn't so helpful (as almost always with libs and ios).

```
Incident Identifier: 445465AF-AE38-40BE-9FEF-875DD439197C
CrashReporter Key:   5108d3729725a56f2cc6f3faeb9a08313e134acf
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             MyTestApp [3910]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/457CA529-5F45-4B79-A1A7-71AF527F805D/MyTestApp.app/MyTestApp
Identifier:          (myidentifer)
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           (myidentifier) [1234]


Date/Time:           2020-05-27 15:28:15.7582 -0300
Launch Time:         2020-05-27 15:28:09.4374 -0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.05.13
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000020a800000008 -> 0x0000002800000008 (possible pointer authentication failure)
VM Region Info: 0x2800000008 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 160524402697  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000283b80000-00000002a0000000 [452.5M] rw-/rwx SM=ZER  
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END
```

I have problems with the device (iPhone XR 13.4.1) and simulator (iOS 13.4). 
I don't have older devices, but with simulator 11.4 and 12.9 I don't have the crash problem (although the method returns NULL, which is an expected result, according to sqlite3 docs, I do handle the null results appropriately).

My SQL statement is `SELECT * FROM 'empInfo'`. which has a working table with valid items.

Has anyone had any problem with SQLite3, SQLCipher, and ios13? Didn't found anything in SO or google...

If any more info help, just ask and I can add it.

**Edit:**
I was able to reproduce the error in this project https://github.com/CarlinhaCamargo/SQLite3_crash_problem

Comment: I don't know why my last commit didn't included the project alteration that is causing the crash. I updated it now.
Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the version of the `libsqlcipher.dylib` in your project. When I removed it and added the latest version via Cocoapods, it resolved the problem. See PR [#2](https://github.com/CarlinhaCamargo/SQLite3_crash_problem/pull/2).

Comment: Sorry that took so long to come back to this question, but just yesterday I had time to generate another libsqlcipher and now sqlite3_column_database_name works fine